# Measure preserving maps of pseudo-Lebesgue measure in infinite-dimensional vector space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I =([0,1),\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ stand for the unit interval with a Lebesgue measure constrained on it. This is just a uniform probability distribution, an infinite power $I^{\infty}$ is a well defined probability space of uniform i. i. d. sequences. Now it completely admissible just to tile $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ with an infinite number of copies of $I^{\infty}$ defining a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu) = \bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^\infty} (I^{\infty} + z)$ with $X = \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. So $\mu$ is a localizable by construction but not $\sigma$-finite.

Then $\mu$ is invariant under $l_0$ shifts. But I don't think it is invariant for $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ shifts as $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]^\infty$ will have measure zero according to my intuition. I think $\mu$ is also invariant under $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$-shifts and $S_\infty$-permutations of coordinates.

Note, that this construction can be repeated for any arbitrary exponent $\kappa$ defining a measure of $\mathbb{R}^\kappa$ with similar properties.

My question is:

If anybody have encountered this measure before? Does it have any better name than pseudo-Lebesgue measure? Is there any nice way to describe the group of affine measure preserving transformations of $\mu$?

Clearly It must contain all transforms generated by $l_0,\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ and $\mathbb{S}_\infty$. There also must be operators which behave as elements of $\mathbf{O}(n)$ then constrained on some finite sets of coordinates and as identity on their complements.

P.S.

I also found the theory of Quasi-invariant measures while writting this question.
But the results I found so far (by A. V. Skorohod ). But this results are mostly about $\sigma$-finite measures and use more complicated construction.

Comment: I've never heard of this measure before, but you're right that $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^\infty$ has measure zero, because its intersection with $I^\infty + z$ has measure zero for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}^\infty$. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Sure, you are right.